# Latitude and Longitude from Shape Files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gis, geopandas, shapefile

I have a shape file which I was able to view as follows:

```
import geopandas as gpd
df_municipalities = gpd.read_file("./CNNNew/Mexico/702825292843_s/mgau2000/agebs_urb_2000.shp")
```

Next I want to extract latitudes and longitudes from the shape files and then download LANDSAT images for those files. I am not sure how to go about that.

I tried something as follows:

```
  df_municipalities['geomlist'] =   df_municipalities['geometry'].apply(lambda x: list(x.exterior.coords))
```

But it still doesn't give me the latitude longitude clearly.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you just want the bounding boxes? Then df.bounds would work. Or the centroid?

Comment: Do you know what kind of coordinate system is being used in the file?